# Org-capture menu, how I go back after selecting a template group?

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

When defining template groups like so:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("a" "Group A"))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("aa" "Group A, Sub-group A"))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("aaa" "Group A, Sub-group A, Option A"))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("aab" "Group A, Sub-group A, Option B"))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("ab" "Group A, Sub-group B"))
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates      '("b" "Group B"))
...
```

If I type the sequence `a` and `a` to get inside the options of sub-group A, is there a shortcut to go back one step, in this case, to the list of subgroups for Group A?

All I see is an abort option that forces me to restart the capture.